# extjs treenode position

Tags: extjs

is there anyway to find the xy position of a treenode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are referring to a `TreeNodeUI` element, all you need to do is get the underlying HTML element using `Ext.get`, then call the `getXY` method. It should be something like this:

```
var extElem = Ext.get(treeNode.getEl()); //the Ext.get may not be necessary in this case.
var xy = extElem.getXY(); //returns [x, y]
```